# web.config single user basic auth

Tags: iis, web-config, basic-authentication

In nginx I can create a authentication response which sends

> WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Private Network"

causing a login for a single user/password to popup without creating a login.aspx

Here's my config settings

```xml
<security>
  <authentication  >
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="test" password="test" />
    <!--<basicAuthentication enabled="true" logonMethod="Batch" />-->
    <!--<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />-->
  </authentication>
</security>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms>
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="test" password="test" />
    </credentials>
  </forms>

</authentication>

<location path="." >
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

However these settings keep taking me to login.aspx which is unwritten.

My goal is to create a simple u/p auth for one user without resorting to login pages or more complex auth.