# .net application basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement a basic authentication in .net. So here i dont want an aspx page.

I only need web.config file and that should ask me for username and password( if i am not wrong we can have browser asking for username and password.)

Currently i have the below code which needs login.aspx page which i want to remove.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="false" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms>
                <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                    <user name="abc" password="abc@123" />
                </credentials>
            </forms>
        </authentication>
        <!-- Unless specified in a sub-folder's Web.config file, 
             any user can access any resource in the site -->
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
            <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />            
            <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
            <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @Martheen Thanks for the quick response but is it possible to handle it from web.config file? I dont need any other file i just want every thing through web.config file

Comment: Prompting for username and password requires JavaScript Code behind.

Comment: Oh, nope, considering [this asker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975280/simplest-way-to-add-basic-authentication-to-web-config-with-user-pass) end up creating an entire HttpModule for it

Comment: @Ares Not necessarily https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: @Martheen is it not possible only using web.config?

Comment: You can define allowed users on webconfig, but the password will be handled by Windows

Comment: @Martheen how do i do that?

Comment: Just list them https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authorization/

Comment: @Martheen Yes but how will i call browser based popup asking for username and password. I dont want to add any aspx file. I am hosting this in azure app service

Comment: You don't, if the user hasn't been authenticated it will ask automatically.

Comment: @Martheen can you share me some sample code for that?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't done in your application. 
This is done in IIS, where you enable basic authentication and disable anonymous authentication.

But if you insist on doing it in code, you can add a HTTP-module, where you can check for basic authentication yourselfs.

E.g.

```
class SurroundingClass
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!Authenticate(context))
        {
            context.Response.Status = "401 Unauthorized";
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");

            // // context.CompleteRequest(); 
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.End();
            return;
        }
    } // ProcessRequest 



    private static string[] ParseAuthHeader(string authHeader)
    {
        // Check if this is a Basic Auth header 
        if (authHeader == null || authHeader.Length == 0 || !authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
            return null;

        // Pull out the Credentials with are seperated by ':' and Base64 encoded 
        string base64Credentials = authHeader.Substring(6);
        string[] credentials = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Credentials)).Split(':');
        if (credentials.Length != 2 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials[0]))
            return null;

        return credentials;
    } // ParseAuthHeader



    private static bool TryGetPrincipal(string[] creds, ref System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (creds[0] == "Administrator" && creds[1] == "SecurePassword")
        {
            principal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity("Administrator"), new string[] { "Administrator", "User" });
            return true;
        }
        else if (creds[0] == "JoeBlogs" && creds[1] == "Password")
        {
            principal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity("JoeBlogs"), new string[] { "User" });
            return true;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(creds[0]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(creds[1]))
        {
            // GenericPrincipal(GenericIdentity identity, string[] Roles)
            principal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(creds[0]), new string[] { "Administrator", "User" });
            return true;
        }
        else
            principal = null;

        return false;
    } // TryGetPrincipal



    // http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication.aspx
    public static bool Authenticate(HttpContext context)
    {
        // DANGER: On the developer system, we need to be able to test it without SSL certificate
        // If Not context.Request.IsSecureConnection Then
        // Return False
        // End If

        string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
            return false;


        string[] credentials = ParseAuthHeader(authHeader);
        System.Console.WriteLine(credentials);

        System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal principal = null;
        if (TryGetPrincipal(credentials, ref principal))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    } // Authenticate
}
```